# LINQ to XML Replace Value Issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am having an issue when trying to replace a value of an XElement.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My simplified xml is as follows

```
<payload>
  <field name="SLUG_LOCATOR">
    <value>ORIG VALUE</value>
  </field>
</payload>
```

Here is my query

```
IEnumerable<XElement> fields =
                    from el in doc.Descendants("field")
                    where el.Attribute("name").Value == "SLUG_LOCATOR"
                    select el;

foreach (XElement el in fields)
            {
                e.Value = "NEW VALUE";
            }
```

If I check el in the for each statement it says that the Value = ORIG VALUE.  So I assumed I could just change that and I would expect to see something like this

```
 <payload>
      <field name="SLUG_LOCATOR">
        <value>NEW VALUE</value>
      </field>
    </payload>
```

But this is what I get and I dont know why

```
 <payload>
    <field name="SLUG_LOCATOR">NEW VALUE</field>
</payload>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're selecting `<field>` element instead of `<value>` element. That's why the entire content of `<field>` get changed to `NEW VALUE`. You can simply modify the `select` part of your LINQ for the slightest change to fix the problem :

```
IEnumerable<XElement> values =
                    from el in doc.Descendants("field")
                    where el.Attribute("name").Value == "SLUG_LOCATOR"
                    select el.Element("value");
```

Or if you need to remain selecting `<field>`s, then change the `for` loop content to :

```
foreach (XElement el in fields)
{
    el.Element("value").Value = "NEW VALUE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the elements that contain the attribute.  Try this to get the `value` subelements:

```
select el.Descendants("value");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but then this new line throws an error - an explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast?

Comment: Oh, try `select el.Descendants("value").FirstOrDefault()`.